# Sync local database with the remote database in php

Tags: javascript, php, database

I have two databases. One in the localhost and another one in the website hosted in hostgator. Both the database have the same schema. I want to sync both the databases on a button click in php.(ie).when i click on a button in php it should copy the newly added data from one database to another database. I tried using Data Replication. But there is no tab called Replication in the phpmyadmin in Hostgator. What method should i follow?Is there any method?

Comment: Being restricted to phpMyAdmin will be a pretty big issue. You're basically going to have to drop all the tables in the destination database, and then export SQL from the source database then execute it on the destination database.

Comment: I want it to happen automatically

Comment: That's not going to happen.